# TextBox windows form c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy realizando una calculadora y me gustaria que en al textbox solo admita que el signo de + o -, solo se pueda poner al principio, que si el usuario intenta ponerlo al final o de segundo no le permite. Solo el textbox admita el signo + o -  si esta en la primera posicion.

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: Intente esto, pero solo hace que no se pueda poner mas de un signo.

 ` private void CajaTexto_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

else if (e.KeyChar == '+')
            {
                TextBox objTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
                if (objTextBox.Text.IndexOf('+') != -1)
                {   
                    //significa que hay un punto decimal
                    e.Handled = true;   
                }
            }
} `

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon allí lo que has intentado

Answer (score 0):

Esto funciona en el evento Text_Changed del textBox:

```
private void CajaTexto_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CajaTexto.Text.Contains('+') || CajaTexto.Text.Contains('-'))
    {
        string temp = "";
        for (int charIndice = 0; charIndice < CajaTexto.Text.Length; charIndice++)
        {


            if (CajaTexto.Text.ElementAt(charIndice) == '+' & charIndice != 0)    //si es '+' y no esta al principio
            {
                temp = CajaTexto.Text.Remove(charIndice, 1);                      //lo removemos
            }
            if (CajaTexto.Text.ElementAt(charIndice) == '-' & charIndice != 0)    //si es '-' y no esta al principio
            {
                temp = CajaTexto.Text.Remove(charIndice, 1);                      //lo removemos
            }


        }
        if (temp != "") CajaTexto.Text = temp;                //si hemos quitado el '+' o el '-' entonces aplicamos los cambios
    }
}
```